# Tomcat startup Hangs

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, tomcat, jenkins

To shutdown tomcat on remote machine as shutdown.bat and catalina.bat stop /f where not working, I killed the tomcat process using below as .bat file in machine and triggering it using psexec to execute bat file having below command.

A.bat

```
for /f "tokens=5" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":6160" ^| find "LISTENING"') do taskkill /f /pid %%a
```

After it when I start the server tomcat server startup hangs after the last line

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "D:\jdk1.8.0_91"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.28\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 62775
```

Nothing is happening in the logs after it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that with your script you kill all the processes and at the time of startup it wait for the debug, try to stop tomcat cleanly, if it hangs tries to find out why at the tomcat  without going through the commands systems

Comment: Well I am trying to stop tomcat cleanly using jenkins but its not working ..
I have tried catalina.bat stop -f and shutdown.bat 
Both of the above command doesnt bring the process which ran the server previously down